# How do I use the user set value of a DAC extension to enable/disable a UI field of the Base DAC?

Tags: acumatica

I added a bool field to APVendorPrice that needs to be enabled only when a SiteID is entered in the APVendorPriceMaint graph.  Likewise, if it is set true, it needs to disable the SiteID field.  By creating a graph extension for APVendorPriceMaint, I can tap into the APVendorPrice_RowSelected event to enable/disable my custom field easily.  However, when I set my new field to Commit Changes = true, the user entry value of my DAC extension field is lost to me.

How do I get the user entered value on my DAC extension field?

```
protected virtual void APVendorPrice_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected baseEvent)
{
    APVendorPrice row = (APVendorPrice)e.Row;
    APVendorPriceExt vendorPriceExt = sender.GetExtension<APVendorPriceExt>(row);

    baseEvent(sender, e);

    PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<APVendorPrice.siteID>(sender, row, vendorPriceExt?.UsrMyField != true);
    PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<APVendorPriceExt.UsrMyField>(sender, row, row?.SiteID != null);
}
```

The GetExtension always returns the saved value rather than seeing that the user toggled the value.

How do I see the user entered value for UsrMyField so that I can enable/disable access to SiteID?

Comment: it seems as if the value is not committed. Also is your bool field setup as a PXDBBool vs PXBool and or have any unbounddefault that might be changing the value? Also try this way of getting the extension in case it helps (as we have needed it once before): vendorPriceExt = PXCache<APVendorPrice>.GetExtension<APVendorPriceExt>(row)

Comment: found another issue in part of the code that I didn't post as well, but also changed the syntax as you suggested.  Seems to work now.

Comment: You can achieve the same result without any code by using the PXUIEnabled attribute - read more here https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/11/pxuienabled-and-pxuirequired-attributes.html